# Извлечение корня n-ой степени в обход натурального логарифма

Tags: delphi, математика, pascal, pascalabc.net, freepascal

Имеется некоторое число x и степенной корень у. Нужно извлечь корень без использования натурального логарифма (`Exp(Ln(X) / 3) и пр.`). Желательно на Pascal, либо Delphi.

Comment: А `Power` использовать можно? :)

Comment: Нет, это нарушает условие задачи.

Comment: Earl, stackoverflow не решает задачи. Сообщество отвечает на вопросы. Какой у тебя вопрос? В чем заключается проблема написать что-то, в данном случае корень логарифма, на паскаль? Пока ставлю минус на "задачу"

Comment: Тогда перефразирую. Как реализовать извлечение из n-го корня без использования натурального логарифма?

Comment: @Earl А ответ вы уже читали?

Comment: С такой постановкой вопроса лучше обратиться на ресурс work-zilla.com - там Вам с удовольствием решат задачу. Здесь же лучше задать вопрос так, чтоб было видно, что Вы сами приложили силы для его решения, но в чём-то застопорились, и это что-то Вам помогут решить конкретным ответом или отсылкой к ресурсам

Comment: @Mbo, да, ознакомился, пытаюсь реализовать. Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

Для вычисления корня `y`-й степени из `X` можно использовать [алгоритм Ньютона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F_n-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8).

Задать начальное приближение-  например, `r0 = 1.`

Посчитать очередное приближение на основе предыдущего (`r{i}` означает подстрочник r<sub>i</sub>)

```
 r{i} = (r{i-1}*(y-1) + X / r{i-1}^(y-1)) / y
```

Продолжать, пока два значения не будут отличаться не более, чем на заданную погрешность

```
function Root(value: Double; n: Integer): Double;
  const
    eps = 1E-10;
  var
    r, rr, pow: Double;
    i, nm1: Integer;
  begin
    r := 1.0;
    nm1 := n - 1;
    repeat
      pow := 1.0;
      for i := 1 to nm1 do
        pow := pow * r;
      rr := (r * nm1 + value / pow) / n;
      if abs(r - rr) <= eps then
        Break;
      r := rr;
    until False;
    Result := rr;
  end;

begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Root(8, 6).ToString); // sqrt(2)=1.4142135623731
```

Comment: Только массив тут вряд ли нужен...

Comment: @Harry Хотел обозначить i-ю итерацию и скобки отличать от круглых

Comment: Если бы не посмотрел в википедию, не понял бы, что обозначает `y` . Где-то у вас потерялась подсказка, что формула приведена для вычисления `X^y` :)

Comment: @Pak Uula Точнее, `X^(1/y)`.  Писал, глядя на заголовок, а потом подправил в соответствии с обозначением из тела вопроса ;)